# Postgresql join 2 tables with km ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, range

i need help with a join with two tables over KM ranges for different distance Numbers. The ranges are different and i need the feature 1 combinate with feature2 and 3.

So I need a join with ranges and don't have any idea how to solve this.
It could be possible that a feature 2 and 3 ist in 2 areas from feature1, then feature1 should be '1'. But i don't have a good idea to do this.

so NR 1 from 0.0 to 0.1 is in feature1 1, with f2=A and f3=X
but NR 3 from 4.2 to 6.0 is in feature1 2 and 1, so the feature1 should be 1

---

```
NR  fromKM  toKM    feature1
1   0       1.4     1
1   1.4     3.8     2
1   3.8     7.2     1
1   7.2     36.7    2
2   0       14.6    1
3   0       5.2     2
3   5.2     10.6    1
```

and

```
NR  fromKM  toKM    featrure2   featrure3
1   0       0.1     A           X
1   0.1     0.3     B           Y
1   0.5     1.3     C           X
1   1.4     2.0     A           X
1   4.0     7.2     C           X
2   0.1     0.4     A           Y
2   0.4     1.6     C           X
3   0.1     4.2     B           X
3   4.2     6.0     B           Y
3   6.0     10.2    A           Y
```

so the output should be

```
NR  fromKM  toKM    feature1    featrure2   featrure3
1   0       0.1     1           A           X
1   0.1     0.3     1           B           Y
1   0.5     1.3     1           C           X
1   1.4     2.0     2           A           X
1   4.0     7.2     1           C           X
2   0.1     0.4     1           A           Y
2   0.4     1.6     1           C           X
3   0.1     4.2     2           B           X
3   4.2     6.0     1           B           Y
3   6.0     10.2    1           A           Y
```

Comment: Post expected output

Comment: edited in orinial post

Comment: `4.0     7.2     2` -- why feature1=2 here?

Comment: sorry, this is wrong, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` using one equality (for `NR`) and two inequalities (for the fromKM and `toKM`). You normally join on equalities, but this is not actually necessary, you can join on *any* expression returning a boolean result.

Assuming your tables are called `t1` and `t2`, you'd use:

```
SELECT
    t1.NR, t2.fromKM, t2.toKM, feature1, feature2, feature3
FROM
    t1 
    JOIN t2
        ON t2.NR = t1.NR AND t2.fromKM >= t1.fromKM AND t2.toKM <= t1.toKM
ORDER BY
    t1.NR, t2.fromKM
```

... and you'll get:

```
nr | fromkm | tokm | feature1 | feature2 | feature3
-: | -----: | ---: | -------: | :------- | :-------
 1 |    0.0 |  0.1 |        1 | A        | X       
 1 |    0.1 |  0.3 |        1 | B        | Y       
 1 |    0.5 |  1.3 |        1 | C        | X       
 1 |    1.4 |  2.0 |        2 | A        | X       
 1 |    4.0 |  7.2 |        1 | C        | X       
 2 |    0.1 |  0.4 |        1 | A        | Y       
 2 |    0.4 |  1.6 |        1 | C        | X       
 3 |    0.1 |  4.2 |        2 | B        | X       
 3 |    6.0 | 10.2 |        1 | A        | Y
```

Which is your desired output (except for one `C`, which I guess was your *smallish* mistake).

You can check the setup and test it at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cb16dfef373a394a0e75cec9738c9a54)*

---

If you would like maximum performance, you can use some specific PostgreSQL features, such as

1. Use the [`numranges`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rangetypes.html) data type, and its ["overlaps" (`&&`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) operator, or the "contains range" (`@>`) one.
2. Use [`GIST` index on the numranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING)

That would mean doing:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t1 ON t1 USING gist (NR, (numrange(fromKM, toKM, '[]'))) ;
CREATE INDEX idx_t2 ON t2 USING gist (NR, (numrange(fromKM, toKM, '[]'))) ;
```

and querying by means of:

```
SELECT
    t1.NR, t2.fromKM, t2.toKM, feature1, feature2, feature3
FROM
    t1 
    JOIN t2
        ON t2.NR = t1.NR AND numrange(t1.fromkm, t1.tokm, '[]') && numrange(t2.fromkm, t2.tokm, '[]')
ORDER BY
    t1.NR, t2.fromKM ;
```

This makes sense when you have large tables. You can check this second specialized option at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=16e520c7ee12618b5756ba2c6afdb99c)*